# convert javascript string to regular expression

Tags: javascript

I have the following

```
    function arrayInArray(chBox, values) {
        try {
            for (var y = 0; y < chBox.length; y++) {
                var stringConcat = "/\b" + chBox[x] + ",?\b/";
                var patt = new RegExp(eval(stringConcat));
                console.log("value to check: " + chBox[y] + " " + values + " index " + patt.test(values));
```

but I can't get it to work. if I change it to this

```
   var patt = new RegExp(/\b17,?\b/)
```

and then run

```
      patt.test(values)
```

it works fine.

I'm passing in

```
   var checkbox = ["17", "23"];
```

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong

thanks

the code that works

```
            for (var y = 0; y < chBox.length; y++) {
                var stringConcat = "\\b" + chBox[y] + ",?\\b";
                var patt = new RegExp(stringConcat);
                if (patt.test(values) == false) return false;
            }
```

Comment: Consider for a moment: What does a backslash within a string literal do?

Comment: If it is an exact copy, why don't you post a link to the solution?

Comment: Because the answers there **are** the solution. That's the whole point of marking something as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for `eval` as its already a string.  Just pass that to the `RegExp` constructor. You should also drop the leading and trailing `/` as that will be interpreted as part of the expression.

Comment: And then there's the issue of backslashes in a string literal not being seen by `RegExp` at all...

Comment: Hi done that and it's still failing to match anything, when I know it should

Comment: Sorted thanks, the code that works